Can current in a wire be used as a test charge in measuring non-uniform Electric Fields?
This seems intuitive and yet not.  For fun I am trying to make a kind of 3-D electric field "compass" to measure the electric field vector in non-uniform fields.  What I am thinking is that if there is a current carrying (voltage applied) straight wire, center tapped, and passing through identical (or atleast precisely calibrated) resistors to ground.  The component length of that wire parallel to the E-field lines should have a slightly different potential between the center tap and the opposing ends of the wire.
This would give a current flow through one of the resistors as slightly higher than the other.  That difference being easily measured could be used to calculate the component of the electric field.  3 of those arranged at 90 degrees to each other would then allow me to measure and compute the Electric field vector at a point in space (assuming the field is non-uniform).
Part of me suspects that it would not work because the field would have no effect on the moving electrons, but I can't articulate why I think that.  Something in the back of my mind is screaming that it would not work, but I can't remember why.
any thoughts?
maybe just a strain gauge attached to an electric dipole.I don't know.  I haven't been able to find a good small electric field probe.  Tons of magnetic sensors but not even one e-field sensor.  Perhaps my searches haven't been phrased well.

The wire is a conductor. It will screen the electric field to the point of having no leftover electric field inside the conductor at the low-frequency limit. Then you will not be able to measure anything.

Thank you.  I should have rested a little before asking
